# Burning Windows ISO with ancient Ubuntu

Tags: iso-image, ubuntu-14.04

I have downloaded Windows 10 ISO last week and would like to create an installation DVD.

Unfortunately I have a DVD drive on a different PC without any OS on it and only limited internet access right now. I have an old installation DVD for Ubuntu 14.04.  I could install Ubuntu 14.04 and burn the ISO (the ISO file is on an USB stick) on DVD. Will it work out? After installing (and not updating) the OS would be 6 years old and the ISO file just few days old, can there be a problem?

Comment: Your plan/idea should work.  But you might be able to save several hours on the install by skipping that step, and instead boot from the Ubuntu DVD and then just use the live GUI.  You would need the the Brasero app to burn a new DVD.

Comment: What tools are you planning on using?

Comment: I want to use brasero, since I cannot Update Ubuntu 14.04 I can only use programs wich are installed directly from Ubuntu DVD.